# PDF bookmark going to the bottom of the previous page in case when caption header is on the top of a page

Tags: hyperref, positioning, links

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter A}
\section{Section AA}
\lipsum
\section{Section AB}
\lipsum
Text

Text

Text

Text

Text

Text

\subsection{Subsection ABA}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter B}
\section{Section BA}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection BAA}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Try to click on PDF bookmark or hyperlink in table of contents (Section AB, Subsection ABA, Subsection BAA). It leads to the bottom of the previous page in case when appropriate [sub]section header is at the top of a page. This is annoying when reading PDF documents in "full page mode" as it goes to the wrong page (the previous one). For some reason the problem does not affect chapter headers. How can it be fixed?

Comment: I suspect bad interaction between `mwrep` and `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg I have also encountered this issue with the article and the KOMA scrartcl classes

Comment: @ArTourter If I change the class to `report` and add a couple of lines before the subsection title so that it goes to the next page, the anchor is correct.

Comment: Here is a hack that seems to work: Use the `needspace` package and add `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` before `\section` -- the number needs to be determined, but this works for this example.  This can be automated to be applied before each `\section`.

Comment: I think that is what @PeterGrill was suggesting by saying the solution can be 'automated'.

Comment: Ok, I see. I just didn't know how to 'automate' it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an automated solution using the *hack* that I commented earlier using [the `needspace` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace).  The `\section` command is redefined to insert `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` before each section.   This ensures that there ar at least three lines available, otherwise the section is begun on a new page.  I think three should be adequate, but if not it can be increased.

So adding this to the preamble fixes the problem with your MWE:

```
\usepackage{needspace}
\let\OldSection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}\OldSection}%
```

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\usepackage{needspace}
\let\OldSection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}\OldSection}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter A}
\section{Section AA}
\lipsum
\section{Section AB}
\lipsum
Text

Text

Text

Text

Text

Text

\subsection{Subsection ABA}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter B}
\section{Section BA}
\section*{Section BB}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection BAA}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't need 3 `\baselineskip`s. 1 was enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Ichibann: Yes `1` works in this case, but in other cases where there is a bit more room at the bottom of the page, but not enough to hold the section header and the first line, then a larger number may be required. So, just keep that in mind...

Comment: This is very useful. One thing though, for me, if I put the definition in the preamble, it gives an error after the table of content (which is a `\section*` by default in my class, ie. `scrartcl`) putting the definition after `\tableofcontent` fixes the problem. I also added a definition for `subsection` and `subsubsection`.

Comment: I didn't see this answer! Remove the parameter from the redefinition of `\section`! It's wrong because it breaks the *-variant and the optional argument. Just end the replacement text with `\OldSection`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for noticing. Have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler solution that also takes care of the starred variants of `\section`or `\chapter` uses the `\pretocmd` command of the `etoolbox`package. Thus, you can write

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{needspace}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\needspace{3\baselineskip}}{}{}
```

to get the desired solution.

A cause for the initial problem can be incompatibilities between the `\hyperref`package and other packages. In my case the offender was the `\titlesec`package which has to come first. After this change in order, the above commands were no longer needed.

Comment: `\preto` is sufficient, for the commands have no argument (but `\pretocmd` doesn't hurt either).

Comment: I found that moving \hyperref below \titlesec worked for me too.